# Has AgGrid a value formatter in case you wanna edited the row?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have some booleans value that I take from the server and from boolean I show yes/no, but the problem is when I want to edit I still get true/false... is any way to fix this?

```
  headerName: 'Website Language', field: 'test', sortable: true,
  filter: true, editable: true, resizable: true, filterParams:
  { textCustomComparator: this.yesNoComparator },
  valueFormatter: this.booleanFormatter(),
  },
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily. Also go through how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `valueGetter` and `valueSetter` instead of `valueFormatter` like this.

```
    headerName: 'Website Language',
    field: 'websiteLanguage',
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filterParams: { textCustomComparator: this.yesNoComparator },
    valueSetter: params => {
      if (params.newValue.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
        params.data.websiteLanguage = true;
        return true;
      } else (params.newValue.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
        params.data.websiteLanguage = false;
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    valueGetter: params => {
      if (params.data.websiteLanguage === true) {
        return 'Yes';
      } else if (params.data.websiteLanguage === false) {
        return 'No';
      }
    }
```